# Custom Configuration Section in system.web

Tags: .net

How can I add a custom configuration section to a .NET web.config file under the existing `<system.web>` section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code

```
<configSections>
    <section name="" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="test" type="DataSetSectionHandler,SectionHandlers" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>


<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <test  attribute="..."  />
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not allowed add custom config sections inside `<system.web>`. You can have your custom config sections under `<configuration>`. Check this [how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: There's also an example of a custom section at http://mike-ward.net/blog/post/00830/creating-custom-configuration-sections-in-web-config.